# perl sort question

Tags: perl, awk

I have some huge log files I need to sort. All entries have a 32 bit hex number which is the sort key I want to use.
some entries are one liners like

```
bla bla bla  0x97860afa bla bla
```

others are a bit more complex, start with the same type of line above and expand to a block of lines marked by curly brackets like the example below. In this case the entire block has to move to the position defined by the hex nbr. Block example-

```
 bla bla bla  0x97860afc bla bla  
     bla bla {  
         blabla  
            bla bla {  
                bla     
            }  
        }
```

I can probably figure it out but maybe there is a simple perl or awk solution that will save me 1/2 day.

---

Transferring comments from OP:

> Indentation can be space or tab, I can enhance that on any proposed solution, I think that Brian summarizes well: *Specifically, do you want to sort "items" which are defined as a chunk of text that starts with a line containing a "0xNNNNNNNN", and contains everything up to (but not including) the next line which contains a "0xNNNNNNNN" (where the N's change, of course)*. No lines interspersed.

Comment: So indentation means that a line belongs to the hex key above it? Is the indentation space or tab? Can "bla bla" contain leading spaces?

Comment: I have edited your post to make it more readable. When you remove those edits, it makes your post difficult to read, which means it becomes less likely to be answered.

Comment: Oh, and can "bla bla" contain numbers? In short, what kind of rules can we use to extract the numbers? You need to be more specific than "bla bla".

Comment: @Martin: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the input format?  I have an idea for a solution, but want to be sure of my assumptions.  Specifically, do you want to sort "items" which are defined as a chunk of text that starts with a line containing a "0xNNNNNNNN", and contains everything up to (but not including) the next line which contains a "0xNNNNNNNN" (where the N's change, of course :) )?  I'm just curious if there might be lines interspersed that you would want to ignore, etc.

Comment: Hi I'm new to this, not sure if comment is the best way to respond.

Comment: Hi, indentation can be space or tab, I can enhance that on any proposed solution, I think that Brian summarizes well,  "Specifically, do you want to sort "items" which are defined as a chunk of text that starts with a line containing a "0xNNNNNNNN", and contains everything up to (but not including) the next line which contains a "0xNNNNNNNN" (where the N's change, of course :) )". no lines interspersed.

Comment: I've transferred your last comment to the question: it is easier for everyone if the question is complete, and you can edit your own question.  Further question: would it be fair to characterize 'paragraphs' as "one line starting with non-blank, followed by zero or more lines starting with blanks (where blank is space or tab or ...)"?  If so, the problem degenerates into 3 phases: (1) read lines, concatenating continuations; (2) filtering interesting paragraphs; and (3) sorting what's left".

Comment: this reg exp works perfectly to extract the key in this case  0x[1-9a-f]\{8\}

Comment: Jonathan - not sure your definition is ok in this case. Paragraph would be  - start (and include this line)  with a line containing "0x[1-9a-f]\{8\}" finish one line before the next line that contains 0x[1-9a-f]\{8\}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work (Not tested):

```
my $line;
my $lastkey;
my %data;
while($line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /\b(0x\p{AHex}{8})\b/) {
        # Begin a new entry
        my $unique_key = $1 . $.; # cred to [Brian Gerard][1] for uniqueness
        $data{$1} = $line;
        $lastkey = $unique_key;
    } else {
        # Continue an old entry
        $data{$lastkey} .= $line;
    }
}

print $data{$_}, "\n" for (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data);
```

The problem is that you said "huge" log files, so storing the file in memory will probably be inefficient. However, if you want to sort it, I suspect you're going to need to do that.

If storing in memory is not an option, you can always just print the data to a file instead, with a format that will allow you to sort it by some other means.

Comment: Drat, you beat me to it.  I was going to give the same solution.  :)  One slight modification, though.  I don't know if all the hex keys are guaranteed to be unique.  If you change the block under the "if" to... `$lastkey = $1 . $.; $data{$lastkey} = $line;` it should take care of the problem (assuming you want identical keys to be sorted in the same order they came in as).

Answer (score 2):

- For *Huge* data files, I'd recommend [`Sort::External`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort%3a%3aExternal).
- It doesn't look like you need to parse the brackets, if the indentation does the job. Then you have to do it on "breaks", or when the indentation level 0, then you process the last record gathered, so you always look ahead one line.

So:

```
sub to_sort_form {
    my $buffer = $_[0];
    my ( $id ) = $buffer =~ m/(0x\p{AHex}{8})/; # grab the first candidate
    return "$id-:-$buffer";
    $_[0] = '';
}

sub to_source { 
    my $val = shift;
    my ( $record ) = $val =~ m/-:-(.*)/;
    $record =~ s/\$--\^/\n/g;
    return $record;
}

my $sortex = Sort::External->new(
      mem_threshold   => 1024**2 * 16     # default: 1024**2 * 8 (8 MiB)
    , cache_size      => 100_000          # default: undef (disabled) 
    , sortsub         => sub { $Sort::External::a cmp $Sort::External::b }
    , working_dir     => $temp_directory  # default: see below
);

my $id;
my $buffer = <>;
chomp $buffer;
while ( <> ) { 
    my ( $indent ) = m/^(\s*)\S/;
    unless ( length $indent ) {
        $sortex->feed( to_sort_form( $buffer ));
    }
    chomp;
    $buffer .= $_ . '$--^';
}
$sortex->feed( to_sort_form( $buffer ));
$sortex->finish;

while ( defined( $_ = $sortex->fetch ) ) {
    print to_source( $_ );
}
```

**Assumptions:**

- The string `'$--^'` does not appear in the data on its own.
- That you're not alarmed about two 8-hex-digit strings in one record.

Answer (score 2):

If the files are not too big for memory, I would go with TLP's solution.  If they are, you can modify it just a bit and print to a file as he suggests.  Add this before the `while` (all untested, ymmv, caveat programmer, etc):

```
my $currentInFile        = "";
my $currentOutFileHandle = "";
```

And change the body of the `while` from the current `if-else` to

```
if ($currentInFile ne $ARG) {
    if (fileno($currentOutFileHandle)) {
        if (!close($currentOutFileHandle)) {
            # whatever you want to do if you can't close the previous output file
        }
    }
    my $newOutFile = $ARG . ".tagged";
    if (!open($currentOutFileHandle, ">", $newOutFile)) {
        # whatever you want to do if you can't open a new output file for writing
    }
}

if (...conditional from TLP...) {
    # add more zeroes if the files really are that large :)
    $lastkey = $1 . " " . sprintf("%0.10d", $.);
}

if (fileno($currentOutFileHandle)) {
    print $currentOutFileHandle $lastkey . "\t" . $line;
}
else {
    # whatever you want to do if $currentOutFileHandle's gone screwy
}
```

Now you'll have a foo.log.tagged for each foo.log you fed it; the .tagged file contains exactly the contents of the original, but with "0xNNNNNNNN LLLLLLLLLL\t" (LLLLLLLLLL -> zero-padded line number) prepended to each line.  `sort(1)` actually does a pretty good job of handling large data, though you'll want to look at the --temporary-directory argument if you think it will overflow /tmp with its temp files while chewing through the stuff you feed it.  Something like this should get you started:

```
sort --output=/my/new/really.big.file --temporary-directory=/scratch/dir/on/roomy/partition *.tagged
```

Then trim away the tags if desired:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^[^\t]+\t//' /my/new/really.big.file
```

FWIW, I padded the line numbers to keep from having to worry about such things as line 10 sorting before line 2 if their hex keys were identical - since the hex numbers are the primary sort criterion, we can't just sort numerically.

Answer (score 0):

One way (untested)

```
perl -wne'BEGIN{ $key = " " x 10 }' \
    -e '$key = $1 if /(0x[0-9a-f]{8})/;' \
    -e 'printf "%s%.10d%s", $key, $., $_' \
    inputfile \
    | LC_ALL=C sort \
    | perl -wpe'substr($_,0,20,"")'
```

Comment: not sure how to test this one, the idea is to cat pipe the input file to it? I'm running in Linux, just in case.

Comment: the input file is the last argument to the first perl invocation, but you can omit that and just pipe to it instead

Answer (score 0):

The solution from TLP worked nice with some minor tweaks. Adding all in one line before sorting was a good idea, next I have to add a pos parsing to restore the code blocks that got collapsed but that is easy. below is the final tested version. Thank you all, stackoverflow is awesome.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $line;
my $lastkey;
my %data;
while($line = <>) {
  chomp $line;
  if ($line =~ /\b(0x\p{AHex}{8})\b/) {
    # Begin a new entry
    #my $unique_key = $1 . $.; # cred to [Brian Gerard][1] for uniqueness
    my $unique_key = hex($1);
    $data{$unique_key} = $line;
    $lastkey = $unique_key;
  } else {
    # Continue an old entry
    $data{$lastkey} .= $line;
  }
}
print $data{$_}, "\n" for (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data);
```